# QT QFileSystemWatcher

Tags: python, linux, pyqt, qt4

It seems simple but it doesn't work.  I have usbautomount installed.

```
#Watch the media directory and connect to enable save csv pb
self.usb_watcher = QFileSystemWatcher()
self.usb_watcher.addPaths(["/media/usb0"])
self.usb_watcher.directoryChanged.connect(self.enable_save_csv_pb)
self.usb_watcher.fileChanged.connect(self.enable_save_csv_pb)
```

I think it has to do with addpath.  If I don't put in the square brackets I get this error message:

```
QFileSystemWatcher: failed to add paths: m, e, d, i, a, /, u, s, b, 0
```

But I've seen examples without the square brackets.

Comment: What happens if you change `addPaths` to `addPath`?

Comment: Same thing.  Nothing when I plug in the usb.  But addPath without the s is correct.  Tried a trailing slash but that didn't work.  Do permissions matter for monitoring?

Comment: @dpetican. You should state in your question exactly what you are doing to test this code. Presumably you're making some kind of changes in the filesystem and expecting to receive signals. Have you tried the same code using paths on other disks?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [addPath](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfilesystemwatcher.html#addPath) instead of [addPaths](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfilesystemwatcher.html#addPaths)

Comment: I think I've been led down the proverbial path.  Correct me if I am wrong but QFileSystemWatcher monitors THE directory itself NOT the contents of the directory which is what I want.  Since the mounts points (directories) already exist then of course the monitored path will not change.  How do I monitor a directory for added or removed files?

Comment: @dpetican. You cannot monitor something that doesn't exist. All you can do is monitor an existing location where it could be created - i.e. its eventual parent directory. So adding or removing files very much count as changes to a directory: see the [documentation for the directoryChanged signal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html#directoryChanged).

Comment: Yes I already read the Docs and  QFileSystemWatcher should do what I want it to do.  Or should it?  Lets be clear this is what I want to happen: 1)  QFileSystemWatcher watches /media/usb0 which initially has no files in it 2) usbautomount detects a usb drive and mounts it at /media/usb0; there are now files in the directory  But here's the rub "are files now in the directory" the same as files added to the directory?

Comment: @dpetican. Obviously not, since the directory *does not change at all* when you mount another filesystem on it. There will never be any files **in** the directory: it's just a node where another filesystem is attached. But anyway, as I suspected, your question is quite misleading, since what you're really trying to do is monitor mount/unmount events, not filesystem changes.